# MariaDB functional index

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to define the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `gid` INT NOT NULL,
  `x` INT NOT NULL,
  `y` INT NOT NULL,
  `z` INT NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY ( `gid`, `x`, `y`, `z` ),
  UNIQUE INDEX `type_index` ( `gid`, ( CASE WHEN `type` = 1 THEN `type` END ) ),
  UNIQUE INDEX `tp_index` ( `gid`, ( CASE WHEN `type` = 2 THEN ... END ) ),
);
```

I want the table to allow only one entry per `gid` when `type` is 1, while it can have *multiple entries per `gid` for any other type*. In MySQL, this query is working fine. However, using MariaDB the query does not work at all.

Result in MariaDB:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '( CASE WHEN `type` = 1 THEN `type` END ) ), UNIQUE INDEX `tppad` ( `gid`, ( CASE' at line 1

How can I solve this error?

In other words: What is the MariaDB equivalent to this?

I am using version `10.2.20-MariaDB-10.2.20+maria~xenial-log`

Comment: Why do you try to use a case statement inside your index definition ? What is your goal ?

Comment: Because only one entry per `gid` with type 1 is allowed, while multiple entries with other types are allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a generated column:

```
type_is_1 boolean generated always as (case when type = 1 then 1 end),
type_is_2 boolean generated always as (case when type = 2 then 1 end),
UNIQUE INDEX type_index ( gid, type_is_1 ),
UNIQUE INDEX tp_index ( gid, type_is_2 )
```

That is MariaDB does not allow expressions as index keys.  But you can easily work around that using generated columns.

Comment: Doesn't work, because I want to allow multiple rows for type = 3 for example.

Comment: @BjörnSchönrock . . . I modified the answer.  The generated columns need to be `NULL` when they are not of the correct type.

Comment: I have been playing with that in the meantime already. Thanks for your answer